# import comma separated text data to java database table

Tags: windows, netbeans, import

I have several large MS Access databases (e.g. 1gb each file), which I want to import to JavaDB Derby database so that whole application can be switched to Java platform. I'm using Windows 7 64 bit/ Netbeans 8.0 (which no more supports JDBC-ODBC). I am using "ucanaccess" to connect to such a large MS access database, now the problem is that the system either takes infinitely long or stops responding, while trying to connet to the MS access database. Is there any other faster and more efficient way to import/ convert such large Access databases (almost 200 databases, 1gb each).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the db size (e.g. 1gb each file) and the number of db, this is definitely out of the scope of ucanaccess. Performance may be dramatically improved (using specific connection parameters), but in this specific case, it doesn't make sense. You should use jackcess directly to get metadata and data.